# How to remove a view in appdelegate method?

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook, view, appdelegate

i want to remove one  viewcontroller's view in appdelegate.m,inside this method - (void) GetUserCompleted i want to remove a view..pleas help me out

below is the FB delegate method,in dis method i want to remove the view containing loginwithFB button,

appdelegate.m

```
- (void) GetUserCompleted
{
    NSLog(@"  %@",fbUserName);
    NSLog(@"  %@",fbmailId);
    NSLog(@"  %@",fblocation);
    NSLog(@"  %@",fbhomeTown);
    NSLog(@"   %@",fbgender);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use something like:

```
    NSMutableArray *allViewControllers = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray: self.navigationController.viewControllers];
    for (id object in allViewControllers) {
        if ([object isKindOfClass:[FacebookClassNameToremove class]]) {
            [allViewControllers removeObject:object];
        }
    }
    self.navigationController.viewControllers = allViewControllers;
```